# I am using a Yolov5 pretrained model, I have successfully created yolov5s. Engine file, but something problem in yolov5_trt.py file. Core dumped

Tags: python, tensorrt, yolov5

I follow all instruction which mentioned (https://github.com/wang-xinyu/tensorrtx/tree/master/yolov5). Getting error while running python yolov5_trt.py file.

python: engine.cpp:1104: bool nvinfer1::rt::Engine::deserialize(const void*, std::size_t, nvinfer1::IGpuAllocator&, nvinfer1::IPluginFactory*): Assertion `size >= bsize && "Mismatch between allocated memory size and expected size of serialized engine."' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

TensorRT-5.1.5
os: Ubuntu 16.04
torch : 1.6.0+cu101
torchvision : 0.7.0+cu101
cuda : 10.1
python : 3.6

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct number of classes in yololayer.h